# Como mostrar um array específico que está em um JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
"id": "1",
"addresses": [
  {
    "num": "1"
    "addressType": "Comercial",
    "country": "Brasil",
    "postalCode": "89035200",
  },
  {
    "num": "3"
    "addressType": "Comercial",
    "country": "Brasil",
    "postalCode": "89035200",
  },
  {
    "num": "3"
    "addressType": "Comercial",
    "country": "Brasil",
    "postalCode": "89035200",
  }
],
```

Como eu poderia retornar todos os "num" pertencentes à "adress" dentro de um array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = {
"id": "1",
"addresses": [
{
  "num": "1",
  "addressType": "Comercial",
  "country": "Brasil",
  "postalCode": "89035200",
},
{
  "num": "3",
  "addressType": "Comercial",
  "country": "Brasil",
  "postalCode": "89035200",
},
{
  "num": "3",
  "addressType": "Comercial",
  "country": "Brasil",
  "postalCode": "89035200",
}
]};
  
const output1 = input.addresses.map(a => a.num);
console.log(output1);
const output2 = input.addresses.map(a => ({"num": a.num}));
console.log(output2);
```

Que tal algo assim, como no `output1` ou `output2`?